# Oracle: Select query where column="Other Language"

Tags: oracle

Table EmployeeDetails has few columns where information is stored in Arabic Language.

Query:

```
Select * from EmployeeDetails where EmpName_Arabic='للبا للبا للب'
```

Query select result should based on matched result only. But unfortunately  it return me unexpected result.

Comment: Can you provide an example of query string and results?

Comment: @Ankit               
 Ex:-  select * from TENDERBASEINFORMATION where ALTERNATESHORTDESCRIPTION ='لب ايلب ال';   Result have more 27 records whether it should have only 1 matched record.

Comment: You really need to add **examples** to your question. We can't see your screen, so it's going to be totally impossible for anyone to know what are those 27 rows

Comment: I just want to know, If we are using input in different language with where clause we have take some extra precaution or it will work same as english input.